# Drawing on Tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I couldn't find a way how to Draw line using grid. I want to have a line going from North to South seperating left and right frames.

```
    self.left= Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.left.grid(column=0, row = 0, pady=5 ,padx=10, sticky=N)

    self.center = Frame (self.tk ,bg= "black")
    self.center.grid(column=1, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky=N)

    self.right= Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.right.grid(column=2, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky=N)
```

I want something like

```
self.w.create_rectangle(self.centerwidth/2-2, 0, centerwidth/2+2, self.windowheigh, fill="#00CC00", outline = "#00CC00")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to separate the left frame from the right one, you can use a separator from ttk module (http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Separator.html)

Here is an example:

```
# python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Separator, Style

# for python2 : 
# import Tkinter as tk
# from ttk import Separator

fen = tk.Tk()

left = tk.Frame(fen, bg="black",width=100, height=100)
# to prevent the frame from adapting to its content :
left.pack_propagate(False)
tk.Label(left, text="Left frame", fg="white", bg="black", anchor="center", justify="center").pack()
left.grid(column=0, row = 0, pady=5 ,padx=10, sticky="n")
sep = Separator(fen, orient="vertical")
sep.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")

# edit: To change the color of the separator, you need to use a style
sty = Style(fen)
sty.configure("TSeparator", background="red")

right= tk.Frame(fen, bg="black",width=100, height=100)
right.pack_propagate(False)
tk.Label(right, text="Right frame", fg="white", bg="black").pack()
right.grid(column=2, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky="n")

fen.mainloop()
```

[image: example]

Comment: btw how do yuo change line's color?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want exactly, but you can create a line like this.

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()

w.create_line(100, 0, 100, 100)
#first 2 args are starting point of line and next 2 are ending point of line.

mainloop()
```

For adding other options, refer to [canvas widget of tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas.html)

Comment: uh I thought you couldn't use pack inside grid

Comment: @IrenaJodeikiene: you can use pack and grid in the same app, just not with  multiple widgets that have a common parent.