# Python 3 Tkinter: How can I create a solid white line to partition widgets from the rest of the program?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently creating a fitness app on Python 3's Tkinter.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x1000+0+0")
root.title("Ultimate Fitness Calculator")
root.configure(bg='darkslategray')
lbl_title = tk.Label(root,text="Welcome to the Ultimate Fitness Calculator by Cameron Su.", fg="white", bg = 'darkslategray')
lbl_title.pack()


Tops = Frame(root, width=1600, height=50, bg="darkslategray", relief=SUNKEN)
Tops.pack(side=TOP)

f1 = Frame(root, width=1600, height=900, bg="darkslategray", relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)



lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('Gill Sans', 50), text="Ultimate Fitness Calculator", fg="white",bg="darkslategray", bd=10, anchor='w').grid(row=0, column=0)

lblInfo = Label(Tops, font=('Gill Sans', 20), text="This multifunctional program calculates Basal Metabolic Rate, Total Daily Energy Expenditures \n and breaks down the amount of macronutrients needed to reach your fitness goals.", fg="white",bg="darkslategray",
                bd=10, anchor='w').grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Once the code is run, you can see what this looks like. I want to create a solid thin white line running across from the left side to the right side, in order to separate this from the rest of the code I plan to implement.

Given the code I already have, how can I do this?

Comment: See this: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/complex.html

Comment: Thanks but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242247/drawing-on-tkinter-grid/38243965#38243965) gives you an example of how to use a separator. It is vertical in the example but you can create a horizontal one using `ttk.Separator(root, orient='horizontal')`.

Comment: How can I configure the coordinates of the separator?

Comment: You don't need to configure coordinates, just pack it with `.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)` right after you pack `Tops` to stick it right under.

Answer (score 6):

There is a ttk widget made for that: `ttk.Separator(master, orient=..., style=...)`. The orient option is either 'vertical' or 'horizontal'.

To make it fill your window from left to right, as fhdrsdg said in the comments, you can pack it using the option  `fill='x'`.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
separator = ttk.Separator(root, orient='horizontal')
frame2 = tk.Frame(root)

frame1.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
separator.pack(side='top', fill='x')
frame2.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

tk.Label(frame1, text='This is the top part.').pack()
tk.Label(frame2, text='This is the bottom part.').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]